# Adding "odd" numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to add only "odd" numbers from a range(named "data") which contains numbers, blank cells and text. No matter what I try I always seem to end up with a #value error. My latest attempt is as follows:
 =SUMPRODUCT(N(MOD(Data,2)=1),Data)
Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason your formula "=SUMPRODUCT(N(MOD(Data,2)=1),Data)" not working is that Excel will sum EVERY row of "Data". As some value in "Data" is not a number, #VALUE error returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Array Formula

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(data), IF(MOD(data, 2) = 1, data, 0), 0))
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering the formula

(Tested in Excel 2003)

Comment: +1. This method allows more flexible criteria than SUMIF().

Comment: Nice answer. It will work in 2007 as well.

Comment: What does the CTRL-SHIFT-Enter do differently?

Comment: @TuxRug: This is called ARRAY FORMULA. It makes a function accept array as argument and return an array. For example, in this case, assume "data" is [1, "a", ""], then ISNUMBER(data) will return [true, false false]. Some reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx

Comment: This answer from Wilson worked a treat, but, when trying to adapt it to "COUNT" instead of "SUM" it fails! Why is this?

Comment: @Auto, this array formula is for counting the odd cells: =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(data), IF(MOD(data, 2) = 1, 1, 0), 0))

Comment: Alternatively, if you like to use COUNT(), this also works: =COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER(data), IF(MOD(data, 2) = 1, data, ""), "")). The reason why you cannot do it by simply replacing SUM with COUNT is that COUNT(range) function returns the number of cells that contain a number within the range. Assume data is [1,2,3,"a",""]. By simply replacing SUM with COUNT, it would become COUNT([1,0,3,0,0]). As all value is number, COUNT() will return 5 (instead of 2 as desired).

Comment: Aha Wilson! Succinct and to the point as usual. Thank you for the explanation as well as the answer.